# Why construct function creates issue in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeigniter 3.x, in codeigniter 3.x when i write

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "ya";
    }
}
```

it shows me error

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

and when i write

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "ya";
    }
    public function index() {
        echo "aya";exit;
    }
}
```

it works fine and shows output as {yaaya}.
can anyone let me know y is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is when you run the url

> http://ip/cifolder/index.php/controller

By default it look into `index()` of this controller

If you use url like

> http://ip/cifolder/index.php/controller/function

It will look into that function of your controller

and if you not written any function in you controller just __construct

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

it means no index() function it will show you `400 error`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because CI was looking for that `index()` when you have not provided which action to go for. For the first case it is not present so it threw the error. But in the second case it was there so it worked. you cant call `__construct()` explicitly.

The default url pattern it look for `controller/action`. If the `action` is not provided the it will look for `index()` in that controller.

So when it get the `index()`, it instantiates the controller class and the `__construct()` get called.